# NSWorkspace openURL prompts a dialog

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-high-sierra

When trying to open a web browser from objective-c:
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];

Instead of opening the user default browser with the URL (e.g. www.google.com), it prompts a dialog asking the user to choose an application to run the document www.google.com.
Moreover, Safari is grayed by default and can't be chosen unless the user explicitly allows all application to be chosen.
After that, choosing Safari actually loads the desired page. But the user experience is awful. Any ideas what could be the cause of that? How can I avoid the dialog and load the page without bothering the user?

Comment: Use a properly formed URL, for example `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: Thanks @red_menace! that indeed did the trick :) much obliged!